# PHP Laravel 5 : Trait not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an issue utilizing traits in a laravel enviroment.

I have attempting to access the trait from wtihin a model in laravel and am getting trait not found error. Below is my trait, this is stored in the app\Traits folder and is named testTrait.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Traits;


trait test{
    public function printTest()
    {
        $test = 'test';
        return $test;
    }

}
```

This is the model I am using to try and access it, this is stored in the app\Models folder and otherwise works fine without attempting to use the trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\testTrait;

class Home extends Model
{
    use testTrait;


    public function someMethod()
    {
        /*
    something here
    */
    }
}
```

I assume it might have something to do with namespacing and the fact that I have to assign the App\Models namespace but even if I change or remove this it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *file* may be named `testTrait.php`, but you've called the *trait* in that file plain old `test`.

```
trait test { ... }
```

Rename it to `testTrait` in the `testTrait.php` file.

```
trait testTrait { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your trait as `trait test{` but in your model you are using wrong trait name `use testTrait;`

change it to

```
use test;
```